# iOS share the localized files between native app and extension app

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

> How do i share a file between native app and extension app. I even
>   tried to move my localized files to shared embedded framework but that
>   also not worked as my expectation. Is that possible to use the
>   containing app localized files in the app extension app?.
>
> Any help that might be appreciated.

Comment: You could use shared user defaults or the shared container.  You may want to look at the documentation for sharing information between an extension and the containing app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6